# Collecting Apple Watch accelerometer data in background

Tags: ios, swift, watchos

I'm trying to make an app that analyzes accelerometer data throughout the day. The app doesn't necessarily need to have constant access to the accelerometer data, it just needs to analyze all of it. So, is there a way to store the data locally and analyze it every hour (if the app is in the dock, maybe). Can it be exported and analyzed at the end of the day? I'm coding in Swift by the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is possible, but rather complex since watchOS3 apps are considered mostly foreground.

1. Once your watchapp will request CoreMotion sensor to record accelerometer data, `CMSensorRecorder().recordAccelerometer(forDuration: ...)`, this data will be recordered by sensor on it's own without any additional impact form your app and stored in system for 3 days.
2. When your app will have execution time (opened in foreground by user or given background refresh task), you can get data by `CMSensorRecorder().accelerometerData(from: startDate, to: endDate)` and process it.

The most difficult thing is to get enough execution time to process and send huge amount of data that will be recordered. Depending on complexity of your analyze methods, you can face problem that OS does not give enough execution time in background refresh task and OS watchdog terminates the process. On the other side, when your app is foreground, it is active only while screen is on and goes to suspended state once screen is off.

If your app is in Dock, it will receive up to 1 background refresh task per hour. If your app will have complication on active watchface, you can get up to 2 background refresh tasks per hour. This number depends on battery state, on how you've been using your previous tasks and on how much tasks are currently used by other apps.

Except background refresh tasks, watchapp can work in background only during workout. In this case duration is not limited, but you can not use more than 15% CPU.

Bottomline:
* you can schedule background refresh tasks once an hour
* once background task starts, start workout so app will be active in background
* return task back to OS asap once workout successfully started
* request accelerometer data from sensor
* process it minding CPU usage
* send to wherever you want and finish workout

WWDC16 sessions to check: [227](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/227/), [235](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/235/), [218](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/218/)

Comment: Where did you get that 15% CPU usage number? Is there any detailed info somewhere?